# Data is not fetching from database in python django

Tags: python, django, database, fetch

I have saved some posts in the database and i am fetching posts to show in list.html. But data is not Showing.

***main Urls.py***

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls',namespace='blog')),
]
```

app url.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'blog'

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.post_list,name='post_list'),
    
path('<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/<slug:post>/',views.post_detail,name='post_detail'),
]
```

Views.py

```
from django.core import paginator
from .models import Post
from django.shortcuts import render, get_list_or_404
def post_list(req):
    posts = Post.published.all()
    return render(req,'blog/post/list.html',{'posts':posts})

def post_detail(req, year,month,day,post):
    post = get_list_or_404(Post,slug=post,status='published',publish__year=year,publish__month=month,publish__day=day)
    return render(req,'blog/post/detail.html',
    {'post':post})
```

list.html

```
<h1>MyBlog</h1>
{% for post in posts %}
<h2>
    <a href="{{post.get_absolute_url}}">a{{post.title}}</a></h2>
<p class="date">
    Published{{post.Publish}} by {{post.author}}
</p>
{{post.body|truncatewords:30|linebreaks}}
{% endfor %}
```

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self) :
        return super(PublishedManager,self).get_queryset()\
            .filter(status='published')

class Post(models.Model):
    
    STATUS_CHOICES = (('draft', 'Draft'),('published','Published'),)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length=250,unique_for_date='publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='blog_posts')
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES,default='draft')
    object = models.Manager()
    published = PublishedManager()
        

class Meta:
    ordering = ('-publish',)
def __str__(self) :
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("blog:post_detail", args=[self.publish.year,self.publish.month,self.publish.day,self.slug])
```

Comment: what's `Post.published.all()`? It's usually `Post.objects.all()`. Can you show the data in your DB and the method `published` in your manager?

Comment: hi @yedpodtrzitko i have added models.py please check.

Comment: Ok please read also the other part of the question I asked. Also what is `object = models.Manager()` for?

Comment: What exactly are you seeing? Are you not seeing anything at all or is just some data missing? Double check your query actually returns results.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko there is showing error in embedding image. let me tell you i have two posts in database - new title, one more post. each have table fields title, slug, author, publish, status,

Comment: hi @sytech, its showing only my h1 tag (myBlog) of list.html and block title nothing else. its not getting anything which is in my for loop in my list.html file

Comment: @RexHoney is that really such problem to copy-paste the data from DB in the question? I dont care about the columns, I know them from the model structure already. I care about the _data_. Most importantly the column `status`, which I assume doesnt have the value `published` there, but it's impossible to get this confirmed from you even after asking about the data two times already.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko  thanks alot. you get it right i have to change status  to published.  now its working. Sorry for not providing complete information.

Answer (score -1):

It's usually Post.objects.all().